# How to control output from crontab?

Tags: command-line, cron

I am trying to run a test case via automation testing (sahi) , so I am running it repeatedly after 1 hour (via crontab).
What I want is that **whenever my test case fails i should receive the email otherwise not.** Right now I am receiving mail whether it passes or fails.
In short, can I send mail to a person depending upon the output I get in terminal.

I am using Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipelineing works in cron just as well as in bash. You could pipe the output to a script, that examines it and sends the mail. Or even easier use grep:

```
# in /etc/crontab

MAILTO=a.b@c.de
SHELL=/bin/bash

# m h dom mon dow user      command
30  * *   *   *   confus    /home/confus/bin/someCommand.sh | grep -A 11 -B 10 "Error:"
```

This will send an e-mail to a.b@.c.de when the stirng "Error: " occures in the output of `someCommand.sh`. In this case the text of the e-mail will be the output from 10 lines before and 11 lines after the occurrence of "Error: " (hence the `-A` for after and `-B` for before).

The mail is only send if the computer running cron has a working mail-server installed. A script to process the output is of course more flexible and considerably more work.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like either the exit code of your command is not being set correctly or that you are sending messages to stdout but not capturing/redirecting it.  On a success, you should return 0 (`exit 0`).  And on a failure return a positive number less than 256 (`exit 2`).  Cron will detect the exit code and send email (MAILTO variable in crontab) on a non-zero exit code.

Also, if any output is sent to stdout or stderr, that is emailed to the user, regardless of the exit code.

See the `cron`(8) manpage for more information.